# One Generic function with lots of parameters or lots of one-use functions in C# (working with XML)

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on an XML file using C# System.XML library.
I need to initially erase all elements of a specific kind, we'll call them item.
After that I need to add each one individually upon request.
These elements have identical child elements and attributes, but potentially different values to each. There are 17 values that could differ between each item element.
What would be better practice:

1. To create one function CreateNode(...) that takes 17 parameters and creates the node with the provided parameters.
2. Create 15 one-use functions, CreateNodeA(), CreateNodeB() etc that each of them creates a specific node, but doesn't take in any parameters?

Edit: adding an example, following user9938's suggestion.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <items>
    <item item_id="1">
      <Name>A</template>
      <SomeInformation>
        <Priority value="low" />
        <InformationChild value="1" times="5"   />
      </SomeInformation>
      <willApear value="yes" when="beginning" />
      <willDisappear value="no" when="" />
      <duration>05:00:00</duration>
      <location>fileLocation</location>
      <extraText>Example</extraText>
      <date>08/03/2022</date>
      <theme>Dark</theme>
    </item>
  </items>
</root>
```

Assuming all attributes, and a most of the element's innertexts can be varied between different items, what would be the better option?

My instincts tell me option 1 is better because it's more generic and will also be able to take in different kinds of nodes in the future if more are added, but creating a function that takes 17 parameters seems... Weird.

Would love to hear your thoughts and opinions.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample XML file to illustrate what you're describing.

Comment: Hey, I added an example to the original post. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: While reading your question, I'm wondering why don't you serialize/deserialize the file and modify the objects in code? That would make working with the data much easier. But there might be a good reason you don't want to go that route. Small tip, in case you didn't know yet, there's also the `Paste Special -> Paste XML as classes` feature in Visual Studio, which saves you a lot of typing.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for telling me about that feature, it'll definitely come in handy haha.

But for your question - I'm not sure what you mean by serializing and deserializing the file?

Comment: To add to what user9938 said, a common pattern is to read XML into one class type then map that class into into another. So for example if you're getting XML from a web API you'd model one class on exactly what's expected from the API then either write code or use something like AutoMapper to convert it to your application classes/types.

Comment: XmlSerialization:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization

Comment: I've never heard of XML serialization until now. From reading about it briefly I think that'll end up solving my issue. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Glad to have been to service :-)